# JQuery .load in Colorbox Parent Div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, colorbox

I am trying to load a php file into a div tag of the underlying page before Colorbox closes. However I can not seem to get the syntax correct. Will .load not work from  Colorbox?

This is what I have

```
parent.$('#notes').load('index.php?&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&customer_id=<?php echo $customer_id; ?>&success=1');
```

I have also tried it with window.parent. Thanks for any clarification on this issue.

Comment: Why do you have that prefixed `parent`? Any errors in the console log?

Comment: the prefix is because that line is executing from an external file loaded in the colorbox. After checking the console I think I might have just found my answer though. It looks like my "token" variable is not coming though correctly. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you've fixed the problem. If you feel my (now updated) answer was half way there (it did state to remove the PHP echo's) please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
parent.$('#notes').load('index.php?&token=12345&customer_id=12345&success=1');
```

Note I've removed the PHP echo's for debugging, just to clarify: this isn't external Javascript to the PHP page? It's embedded in the page using `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`?